# find non LaTeX characters (eg. acute accents) with regex in vim

Tags: vim, latex, regex

I was pasting bibtex references into bibex. some names contain characters that latex skips. for example, á. is there a way in vim or regex to search for all characters that are skipped by latex? one way I would think is to write in regex to search for anything that doesn't contain 0-9, a-z, A-Z and some characters like / \ $

Comment: one way to solve the problem is to use latex package '\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}' but i would still like to search for acute accent characters

Comment: Seems to me like it would be better for SO as it is more about regex than vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with which characters LaTeX ignores, but if the file you are editing is encoded in UTF-8, you might try searching for characters outside the ASCII repertoire (0–127; or 32–127).

As a search command in Vim:

```
/[^\d0-\d127]

/[^\d32-\d127]
```

You can also use hex or octal instead of decimal; see [`:help /[]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fcollection). This requires that `l` and `\` not be present in the value of [`cpoptions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cpoptions%27) (they are not present in the default state).

This should work for any encoding that is “the same as ASCII (where it is defined)” (i.e. UTF-8 and most “latin” encodings). If you are dealing with an encoding that clashes with ASCII, then you will need to refine the range specification.